# Element is moving while the page is loading - CSS issue?

Tags: html, css

This is **[my site](http://www.gameron.pl/).**

I have a problem with the site logo - only in Chrome and Opera, it just moves a little while loading (from left to right) and then jumps back to its place.

I had an issue with Chrome and Opera back in the day with my logo, but I fixed it by adding this code:

```
#nav-header.nav-container { 
  margin-left: 165px;
}
```

(without this code, my navigation overlays logo - of course only in Chrome and Opera).

To notice the issue, you have to refresh the page a couple of times (by clicking on site logo).

I tried adding various css but no luck. What can be responsible for this behavior? It's really odd that it only happens in Chrome and Opera.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

This is the code for site logo:

```
.site-title a img{
    height:40px !important;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:auto !important;
    top:-27px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-bottom:5px !important;
    padding-top:5px !important;
}
```

Comment: i cannot replicate your problem. i refreshed the page not a couple but about 20 times, still couldn't replicate the issue you are describing

Comment: Did you refresh the page by clicking on logo image? If not, it's the only way to notice the issue

Comment: yes. by clicking the logo every time.

Comment: Please can you create a [mcve] of your problem within the question - see [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Have you already tried absolutely positioning the logo?

Comment: @rawnewdlz

Hmm, it actually works, but after applying position:absolute to .site-title a img, it dissapears on resolution below 719 px. If I add position:relative to resolution below 719px, the same "jumping" problem starts occuring on mobile

Comment: @Pete,

edited the post

Comment: I managed to fix the logo issue. Now there's a issue with first menu item "Newsy" - it jumps a little. Any ideas?